# Excel VSTO cell precision

Tags: excel, vsto

When I read very small values from Excel sheet these are shown as scientific precision. For example, the -0.00002 is always read as -2E05 using Cells().Values function. Below are the conversion lines I have used, without any success. How to get the actual value instead of the scientific format?

```
  var canConvert = decimal.TryParse(ws.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString(), out _); // result in false
  var cellString = ws.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString("R"); // -2E05
  var cellStrin2g = ws.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString(); // -2E05
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set up the required [NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) first:

```
ws.Range("A17").NumberFormat = "General"
```

The format code is the same string as the Format Codes option in the Format Cells dialog box.

Comment: I am afraid this does not solve the issue. The excel shows correctly the value in the cell, in general format, however when you execute above snippets they always returned in Scientific Format.

Answer (score 0):

After several trial I have came up to the following solution, which works well in my model.

```
double number = 0;
var canConvert = double.TryParse(ws.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString(), out number3);
if (canConvert)
  string doubleAsString = cell.ToString("F99").TrimEnd('0');
```

Bear in mind that the above scenario works well upto 99 following digits. Feel free to extend it to your needs.